# Porting PLX 32-bit device driver to 64-bit driver

Tags: windows, 64-bit, driver, device-driver, 32-bit

Before I ask my question, here's some background information so that you might have a better understanding of what I am trying to accomplish. I have searched around and found similar questions but none that are specifically what I am asking.

I am trying to port over a modified 32-bit PLX Pci9056 device driver to 64-bit. I also have a few User apps that utilize the driver. PLX provides a complete SDK, including the PLX API in a dll, driver source code, and tools to create and debug user apps. It uses the Windows DDK build environment to build the drivers. The following is how they all interact:

User app --> PLX API --> PLX Pci 9056 driver --> PLX chip

The 32-bit driver has been tested on Windows 7 32-bit and works properly. I believe I should be able to simply rebuild the driver in the 64-bit Windows DDK build environment (Of course after handling any pointer casting. Please correct me if I am wrong.) At this point the driver should run properly on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine.

I understand that usually 32-bit apps will run fine on a 64 bit machine, but in this case the User app is using the PLX API which was initially built only to support 32-bit. Will my User app still work in a 64-bit OS without updating it, or will I run into issues?

Comment: I think the only possible answer is "it depends".  One obvious potential issue is that if the data structures used to communicate between the DLL and the driver contain elements that are different sizes in the two environments, you'll need to change the driver to accommodate that.  If the driver does something unusual like mapping into the user process memory space, there might be issues with that (I'm not sure) and of course any driver that's only been tested in 32-bit may be making unsafe assumptions.

Comment: Ok, those are the general problems I initially thought might arise. I guess I'll just build and do some testing.

Comment: 32-bit apps will load 32-bit DLLs and work with 32-bit device drivers. consider it a completely separate subsystem on a 64-bit windows

Comment: Hello, you got any luck with this? @btse

Answer (score 0):

The PLX PCI SDK (now Broadcom PCI/PCIe SDK) has supported both 32b/64b drivers with the same source code for many years now.  Special macros are used when required, etc.  In Windows, your 32-bit app will work fine due to WOW layer.  The PLX IOCTL structures always store pointers in 64-bit fields to ensure the structure does not vary if you build a 32-bit app.  The SDK also provides 64-bit build of the API library, so you can also build your app as native 64-bit.  The same app level source code, for the most part, should work in both Windows & Linux. The samples provided in the SDK are all identical source for both Win/Linux.